# UIAlert during splashcreen

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

This is a two part question.

1. I have created a user agreement that the user must agree to when first launching the app (it is an alert with some information and  agree/ do not agree button)

I call upon the method that creates this alert inside myAppDelegate.m and within the method

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

The problem is the alert pops up when the splash screen has finished loading and my first view comes up. I want this to happen during the splash screen. How would I do this?

The second question is When the users presses the "Do not agree button", I want them to exit the app so I have programmed it with

```
                      exit(0);
```

Is there a better way and will apple reject my app because of this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can't -- during the splash screen (your default.png) the app is loading into memory, and it cannot therefore execute any code, including presentation of a UIAlertView. That's why you don't see the alert until the splash disappears -- removal of the splash screen is the last thing that the app does before calling `applicationDidFinishLoading:withOptions:`.

What you *can* do is create a view controller that mimics your splash screen. This is easy -- you can even reuse `default.png` as a background if you want, though a better idea is just to present in this first view controller your agreement text and agree/disagree buttons.

As to your question re: use of `exit()`, it's best to avoid doing that. If the user refuses, you can simply do nothing. Of course, if you go the view controller route as I suggest, you can leave presented another opportunity for the user to agree.

Another thought is that Apple allows you to customize the EULA of your app when you upload a binary -- you could put it there and be covered.

Answer (score 0):

Why not load our default.png as the background of you initial view and just handle the Alert in it's controller. you can always add another view or segue based on the answer.

The problem is the UIAlert blocks the Main thread, so it could stop your app from launching in time, and the process could be terminated.